# How to get the intersection item between two dataframe columns?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

[Image example] 
[image]

As shown in picture above, how can I find the total number of the item that appeared in both 'Actual' and 'prediction' columns for every userId? The type is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.

The code to construct the example table as following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists 
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[32, 256, 5, 102, 74, 171, 270, 111, 209, 24],
                [1, 258, 257, 281, 10, 269, 14, 13, 272, 273],
                [258, 260, 264, 11, 271, 288, 294, 300, 301],
                [9, 10, 11, 12, 22, 28],
                [1, 514, 2, 516, 4, 13, 526, 527, 1037, 529, 256, 678],
                [1, 1028, 7, 9, 1033, 15, 1047, 25, 546, 1061],
                [258, 259, 514, 261, 131, 135, 520, 265, 1028, 50],
                [2, 11, 12, 526, 1044, 22, 23, 27, 541, 54, 88],
                [332, 168, 79, 343, 38, 1007, 9, 232, 381, 1079],
                [38, 168, 561, 542, 69, 20, 79, 385, 332, 480]]))

test_actual = data.rename(columns={0: "Actual"})
test_actual['userId'] = [1,2,3,5,6,8,10,12,15,18]
test_actual = test_actual.set_index('userId')

data2 = [[154, 248, 237, 223, 83, 283, 69, 32, 480, 325],
         [332, 168, 38, 9, 385, 258, 561, 41, 79, 542],
         [322, 258, 226, 232, 1007, 343, 332, 260, 561, 381],
         [237, 154, 196, 223, 523, 277, 226, 748, 323, 28],
         [168, 332, 38, 9, 83, 561, 232, 526, 1007, 20],
         [79, 38, 480, 168, 232, 561, 653, 9, 542, 996],
         [9, 232, 332, 523, 168, 322, 7, 1028, 41, 542],
         [83, 168, 232, 322, 385, 223, 154, 941, 283, 12], 
         [69, 38, 196, 480, 83, 385, 20, 343, 283, 542], 
         [480, 38, 69, 83, 385, 154, 542, 941, 283, 223]]

test_actual['Predict'] = data2
test_actual
```

Your opinion and help will be much much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Not real clear what you are after - what would your expected result be for the example data?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, the expected result for the example data is the number of items that intersection between both Actual and Predict columns. I found your suggestion comment below and it is helpful for me! Thank you so much for your help. I will improve my questioning skills when publishing another question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can use numpy intersect1d,

```
test_actual.apply(lambda x: len(np.intersect1d(x['Actual'],x['Predict'])), axis = 1)

userId
1     1
2     1
3     2
5     1
6     1
8     1
10    1
12    1
15    2
18    5
```

If you are interested in values and not the count, use

```
test_actual.apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x['Actual'],x['Predict']), axis = 1)

userId
1                        [32]
2                       [258]
3                  [258, 260]
5                        [28]
6                       [526]
8                         [9]
10                     [1028]
12                       [12]
15                  [38, 343]
18    [38, 69, 385, 480, 542]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was spent more than 5 hours on this, and your comment is helpful, it solved my problem with just two lines. I will learn from this experience and learn about the `apply `.

Answer (score 1):

Without further details, e.g., how many classes, how long the dataset, `apply` seems to be the only viable choice:

```
(test_actual
   .apply(lambda x: set(x['Actual']).intersection(set(x['Predict'])),
                               axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
userId
1                        {32}
2                       {258}
3                  {258, 260}
5                        {28}
6                       {526}
8                         {9}
10                     {1028}
12                       {12}
15                  {38, 343}
18    {480, 385, 69, 38, 542}
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, it seem like `apply` is the best method to solve my problem, I really appreciate your help! I haven't heard about `apply` before until post the question here.